# Where to setState the props value coming from parent component in child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a home screen/page in a website with a lot of forms which have both the functionality of add/edit actions.During the edit i have seen the problem as the api call is made and after the data come from api i have to prefill the data in their respective form fields in modal popup.But the issue i am facing is that how can i setState the child component's state using the props coming from parent component before the modal opened so that the data can be seen in the modal and can be edit also. **I am confused, where i should do the setState?(i have tried in onOpened behaviour of modal but setState is asnychronous so i faced some problem, should i do in componentDidMount or where ?)** 
Here is link to my work. https://codesandbox.io/s/mj6ww6m718?fontsize=14

**Parent component**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import ModalComponent from "./modal";
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          openModal: false,
          name: ""
        };
      }

      toggleModal = () => {
        this.setState({ openModal: !this.state.openModal });
      };

      render() {
        console.log("render from index");
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.toggleModal}>Open Modal</button>
            <ModalComponent
              openModal={this.state.openModal}
              toggleModal={this.toggleModal}
              name={this.state.name}
            />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**Child component**

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import {Modal,ModalHeader,ModalBody,FormGroup,Input,Col,Label} 
       from "reactstrap";

    class ModalComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          name: ""
        };
      }

      handleInput = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
      };

      render() {
        console.log("render from modal");
        return (
          <div>
            <Modal
              isOpen={this.props.openModal}
              onOpened={this.onModalOpened}
              toggle={this.props.toggleModal}
            >
              <ModalHeader toggle={this.props.toggleModal}>Header</ModalHeader>
              <ModalBody>
                <FormGroup row>
                  <Label col-8>Name from Parent state after api call</Label>
                  <Col col-4>
                    <Input
                      type="text"
                      name="name"
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.handleInput}
                    />
                  </Col>
                </FormGroup>
              </ModalBody>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default ModalComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child component you will have

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({name: nextProps.name})
  }
```

but in newer version of React this will be replaced with `getDerivedStateFromProps` you can learn more about getDerivedStateFromProps [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: This will work, but remember `componentWillReceiveProps` is depricated in latest react versions. Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` instead.

Comment: @MithunGS I have mentioned it but in newer version of React this will be replaced with getDerivedStateFromProps you can learn more about getDerivedStateFromProps